# "Typed property must not be accessed before initialization" error in PHP 7.4+

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, soap-client, php-7.4

I'm using PHP 7.4 and property type hints.

Let's say I have a class A, with a couple of private properties. When I use \SoapClient, Doctrine ORM, or any tool that instantiates a class bypassing the constructor and getting/setting properties directly using reflection, I face an error `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Typed property A::$id must not be accessed before initialization in`.

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

class A
{
    private int $id;
    private string $name;

    public function __construct(int $id, string $name)
    {
        $this->id   = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

$a = (new \ReflectionClass(A::class))->newInstanceWithoutConstructor();

var_dump($a->getId()); // Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Typed property A::$id must not be accessed before initialization in ...
```

I can mitigate this problem by declaring properties as nullable and setting a null value by default.

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

class A
{
    private ?int $id      = null;
    private ?string $name = null;

    public function __construct(?int $id, ?string $name)
    {
        $this->id   = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

$a = (new \ReflectionClass(A::class))->newInstanceWithoutConstructor();

var_dump($a->getId()); // NULL
var_dump($a->getName()); // NULL
```

However, I don't like this workaround. The point of my class is to be domain compliant and encapsulate domain constraints within the class design. In this case, the property `name` shouldn't be nullable. Potentially I can declare the property `name` as an empty string, but it doesn't seem like a clean solution as well.

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

class A
{
    private ?int $id     = null;
    private string $name = '';

    public function __construct(?int $id, string $name)
    {
        $this->id   = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

$a = (new \ReflectionClass(A::class))->newInstanceWithoutConstructor();

var_dump($a->getId()); // NULL
var_dump($a->getName()); // ''

$idProperty = new \ReflectionProperty($a, 'id');
$idProperty->setAccessible(true);
if (null === $idProperty->getValue($a)) {
    $idProperty->setValue($a, 1001);
}

$nameProperty = new \ReflectionProperty($a, 'name');
$nameProperty->setAccessible(true);
if ('' === $nameProperty->getValue($a)) {
    $nameProperty->setValue($a, 'Name');
}

var_dump($a->getId()); // 1001
var_dump($a->getName()); // Name
```

**My question is**: is there a way to keep a proper class design and avoid facing the `Typed property must not be accessed before initialization` error? If no, what is the preferred approach to tackle this problem? (e.g. define all properties as nullable nulls or string properties as an empty string, etc.)

Comment: You access it before it is declared. So simplest thing is declare with a default value like `private int $id = 0;`. If you don't, the initial value is NULL.

Comment: But it would make the class state invalid from the domain perspective, as 0 is not a proper ID. Looks very hacky.

Comment: I think having an int to be able to be NULL is much more hacky and violates type safeness, even it is possible, in my taste.

Comment: Yeah, it's very far from ideal. I don't like make it either nullable or 0 by default. I hope there is a clean solution for the problem.

Comment: When you access `getId(): int` you expect an int, but when it is NULL, of course that is not right. So you need to return an int, and check for yourself like by `return (int)$this->id;`. Then NULL will be casted to 0. Or change signature to `getId(): ?int`.

Comment: $id is already null by default.  It's just that when you declare that getId() returns an int, php 4.4 takes your word for it and says oops, null is not an int.  I think you are tying yourself up in knots trying to use getId() on an object which you say is invalid.  By the way, it's not reflection that is the culprit here.  It's using getId().

Comment: If I use \ReflectionProperty instead of getters to get a value it triggers the same error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think there's a misunderstanding here. Uninitialized typed properties have no state, which means they have no initial `NULL`. If you want a property to be `NULL` you have to specify it explicitly.

```
private ?string $name = NULL;
```

So your attempt to avoid this exception without setting these properties is just not right and makes no sense!. The purpose of typed properties is to avoid implicit initialization and always provide an explicit value that is clear and makes sense. And please don't just define all properties as nullable to make this exception disappear!! as this will defeat the whole point of typed properties and PHP 7.4 .

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would it be better to define int property as zero and string property as an empty string? Null indeed seems a bit odd, as my class shouldn't accept null for id or name.

Comment: @MikhailProsalov Yes, it is definitely better to initialize properties with values of the same declared type. And it was a design objective from the PHP team to drive developers to always provide an explicit initialization.

Comment: But what should we do with nullable relations fields? If we set null as default value then lazy loading doesn't work because doctrine for weird reasons doesn't fill it with proxy entity object

Answer (score 1):

Let's simplify things and clarify how Reflection based ORM's such as Doctrine work.  In particular, Doctrine only uses reflection when loading an object from the database.  So id will always be set.  Consider:

```
class Entity
{
    public int $id;

}
$entity = (new \ReflectionClass(Entity::class))->newInstanceWithoutConstructor();

$idProperty = new \ReflectionProperty($entity, 'id');
$idProperty->setValue($entity, 1001);

echo 'ID ' . $entity->id . "\n";
```

The above example works without the error message.  You won't be using reflection to create a class without a constructor unless you plan on setting all the properties as well.

At  this point, the only question is what you want a 'properly designed' class to do with:

```
$entity = new Entity();
echo 'ID ' . $entity->id . "\n";
```

If it is considered to be okay for id to be null before the object is persisted then you go the ?int route.  If not then maybe consider using a guid instead of a sequence.